# preventDefault not working when ismap is added to the image link in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, firefox

I'm working on a test in creating a map editor, when clicked on an image, 
it will show the result of the clicked point

I don't want to reload the page so I used preventDefault() when
 the user clicks on  the map..

I tried this in chrome and it works fine, but on firefox, it is just reloading..

I also tried removing the `ismap` attribute in the image and the `preventDefault()` worked.
But still, I want the `ismap` attribute to be included in the `img` tag

I searched for similar problems, tried to solve it based on their suggestions and
came up to these code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#test').bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //some more codes here..
            $('#output').append('success');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="preventDefault.html" id="test"><img src="aup.jpg" ismap="ismap"/>      </a>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the file name is `preventDefault.html`

still, the code works on chrome but negative on firefox
what I want is, if i clicked on the image, 'success' should append to `#output`

I'm working on Firefox 26.0
and Chrome 31.0.1650.63

[ADDITION]

Well, what I want to create later is a map editor, where if the user clicks on ANY area of the image, it will return the coordinates and later will be saved to a certain file.. this is a tutorial I'm following: [complex shapes](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/2/5). Well, I want the link not to reload..
However, it is different from the suggested duplicate link

```
<map>
   <area>
</map>
```

tags since the `<map>` tag already have fixed coordinates linked to the image..hope I cleared the misunderstanding.. :)

Comment: Why wrap it in a link? It's the map's default you want to cancel

Comment: i wrapped it in a link because I will be needing the coordinates of the image in my later coding.. I wish to get the coordinates' value so through ajax.. that's why..

Comment: Add the #map and handle coords there

Comment: thanks for that link, but the link that you suggested is using a map tag and not img tag... if I would follow that, I need to restructure my code so that it will follow the maps default.. thanks for that but It still bugs me why my code doesn't work in firefox.. :) thanks..

Comment: The reason you have an issue is that the browser executes the image ismap default before you get your anchor action executed

Comment: Well, I partially got your explanation, however, can you suggest or answer what will be the best code regarding this problem.. thanks :)

Comment: Yes handle your events in the image map as you are supposed to. Look at the code in the duplicate I posted. I'm on my phone so I cannot show you

Answer (score 0):

As you say that removing the ismap attribute in the image and the preventDefault() worked, maybe the issue is with this attribute.

To use custom data attribute in HTML5, you must use the `attr` tag before the attribute name, so you attribute name should be `attr-ismap`.

More info about HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*): http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Try this fix and tell me, hope it helps!

**[EDITED]**

`ismap` is a custom attribute of img tag, so it is not necesary to became a HTML5 Custom Data Attribute.

Sorry!

Comment: well, i tried it, but as far as I know, `ismap` attribute is not just an ordinary attribute since if you include it in an img tag, you can get the coordinates of the pixels of the image.. correct me if I'm wrong but it is not a customized data.. :)

Comment: @catzilla you are totally right, i was confused, sorry!
Have you tried with just `ismap` and not `ismap="ismap"`??

Comment: no problem, I also learned new customized attributes thanks to your suggestion.. :).. Yeah, I already tried just using `ismap` rather than `ismap="ismap"`, but it still didn't work..

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery.ajax()` to avoid reload the page rather using `preventDefault`?

Info about `jQuery.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: talking about `jQuery.ajax()`, I'm going to use it later inside the click event of the link.. I use `preventDefault()` to prevent reloading of the page so that I can successfully use ajax as the user clicks the image.. therefore, `preventDefault()` is still essential.. :)